# How to cache query and mutation from GraphQL in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, caching, graphql

I have an app that retrieves data from GraphQL, the app has query and mutation requests, each screen of the app has at least one or more query to retrieve data from GraphQL and some of them has mutation requests to send data, all query receives values from earlier screens to get new data according with what was opened.

I am using the package [hasura_connect](https://pub.dev/packages/hasura_connect) to retrieve and send data, the package accepts an interceptor which I am about to test the package [shared_preferences_cache_interceptor](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences_cache_interceptor) but it only caches query, not mutation and the other problem is, the query receiveis parameters from earlier screens before making requests.

What is the best way to cache query and mutation considering that situation?

```
import 'package:hasura_connect/hasura_connect.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class GraphQLHelper {

  static final String host = 'https://apigraphql.staging....';

  static HasuraConnect _hasuraConnect;

  static Future<dynamic> query({
    String path = "",
    @required String docQuery,
    @required Map<String, dynamic> variables,
    Map<String, String> headers
    }) async{


    _hasuraConnect = HasuraConnect(
      host+path,
      headers: headers,
      reconnectionAttemp: 0
    );

    try{

      var data = await _hasuraConnect.query(
          docQuery,
          variables: variables,
      );

      //print("query DATA: $data");

      return data;

    } catch(e){
      print("query ERROR: $e");
      CustomToast.error(Errors.get(e));
      return null;
    }


  }

  static Future<dynamic> mutation({
    String path = "",
    @required String docMutation,
    @required Map<String, dynamic> variables,
    Map<String, String> headers}) async{


    _hasuraConnect = HasuraConnect(
        host+path,
        headers: headers,
        reconnectionAttemp: 0
    );

    try{

      var data = await _hasuraConnect.mutation(
          docMutation,
          variables: variables
      );

      //print("mutation DATA: $data");

      return data;

    } catch(e){
      print("mutation ERROR: $e");
      CustomToast.error(Errors.get(e));
    }

  }


}
```